# Making flex items behave like fluid text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way of making flex items like this:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

div:not(.container){
  word-break: break-word;
  background:blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Looooooooooooooooooong text looooooooong</div>
  <div>Smooll</div>
  <div>Smoll</div>
</div>
```

Behave like fluid text? So that "Smooll" is on the same row as the ending of "looooong text"? As if they weren't in a flex, but rather just normal text? The number of items is dynamic. Thank you for reading!

Edit:

I need to use flex to take out an element (which could be any, dynamically) based on an additional class on the given item. The end result is this:

[image]

Comment: No, that is not possible. If you don't want flex behavior, then don't use flex in the first place.

Comment: I need to use flex because I have to pull an item out of the regular order and put it in front of everything in the regular flow.

Comment: Okay, fair point, but you will have to find a different way to do this then, I think. "flex" and "regular flow" don't really go together.

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs use float ... and try to ask your question describing your use case rather than describing the solution you are trying to use. You will have better luck to get answers if you describe the use case.

Comment: Updated the question. I don't think this could be achieved with floats.

Comment: Regardless, if you use flexbox this is not possible. Your issue is the re-ordering and so I'd suggest you refocus the question on that problem since it cannot be solved with flexbox.

Comment: *I don't think this could be achieved with floats* --> I think it possible but if you don't share a clear use case with a relevant code we cannot verify

Comment: How could this be achieved with floats?

Answer (score -1):

One solution I’ve seen cases like this approached with is to wrap every character in `<span>` with `white-space: break-spaces`. This gives you regular text flow-ish layout with flexbox.

Then you can identify multiple characters that are part of the same “unit” with a class. For example:

```
<style>
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  display: block;
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
</style>

<div>
  <span class="part1">L</span>
  <span class="part1">o</span>
  <span class="part1">o</span>
  ...
  <span class="part1">n</span>
  <span class="part1">g</span>
  <span> </span>
  <span class="part2">S</span>
  <span class="part2">m</span>
  <span class="part2">o</span>
  <span class="part2">l</span>
</div>
```

Without knowing more about your setup, maybe an approach like this could work?

You could also experiment with wrapping words in `<span>` instead of individual characters and using the `column-gap` CSS style for spaces.